# Adding a vector to a specific row of a matrix with numpy

Tags: python

Hey I want to try to solve the following question using numpy: given two quadratic matrices of different sizes and a Textfile with the information of row indices. I want to add the row of the smaller matrix to the row of the bigger matrices at the corresponding indices. For example:

The small matrix is given as

```
    1 2 3 
    4 5 6
    7 8 9
```

The big matrix is a zero matrix for example of size 8

```
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The text file has now the following entries:

```
    1
    3
    6
```

Now the first row of the smaller matrix has to be added to the first row of the bigger one. The second row to the third row and the last row added to the sixth row i.e.

```
    1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 4 5 6 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 7 8 9
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I tried it with a lot of for-loops but it is not working at all.

Comment: How do you decide the starting column in a given row to add?

Comment: Note that indices in Python and in numpy are zero-based, so your example actually added to rows `0`, `2`, and `5`. Is that really what you want? Also, what is a "quadratic matrix"?

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted. In Germany we call a matrix quadratic if it has the shape (n,n). The starting column is the same as the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume you have 2 matrices:

```py
import numpy as np

m1 = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9,]])
m2 = np.empty([8, 8])
m2.fill(0)
```

And a list of positions is defined:

```py
li = [1, 3, 6]
```

The list defines to replace values of the matrix `m2`, by the rows of the matrix `m1`, at the positions `[0][0:2]`, `[2][2:4]` and `[5][5:7]`.

Values of numpy arrays can be replaced by [`numpy.put()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.put.html).
Calculate the indices of the values to be replaced and replace the values:

```py
ri = [(v-1) * m2.shape[1] + v - 1 + j for v in li for j in range(m1.shape[1])]
np.put(m2, ri, m1)
```

Output:

```py
print(m1)
print(li)
print(m2)
```

> ```
> [[1 2 3]
>  [4 5 6]
>  [7 8 9]]
> [1, 3, 6]
> [[1. 2. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
>  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
>  [0. 0. 4. 5. 6. 0. 0. 0.]
>  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
>  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
>  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 7. 8. 9.]
>  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
>  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
> ```

---

If you don't want to replace the indices, but you wat to add the values to the current matrix, then you have to sum the values in a loop, instead of replacing by `np.put`:

```py
for i in range(len(ri)):
    m2.flat[ri[i]] += m1.flat[i]
```

Comment: If I have another small matrix M3 can I also use np.put and it will be added or will it be replaced? Edit: I just tried it out. It will replace it. Is there a way to add it?

Comment: Yes if I have a smaller matrix M3 of the same size with same list of position it should add the values. np.put is replacing them. Is there a command to add them?

Comment: @Kerem See the extesnsion to the answer.